# Monitoring LVM Thin Pool with lvs -a regularly using Zabbix (or any other method)

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-space-utilization, zabbix

For my OpenStack setup, I'm using LVM as Cinder Block storage backend. I've created a cinder-volumes vg for Thin Provisioning.

Now, I want to monitor how much that vg is used (not seperate disks in that). I found that lvs -a can do this. I was able to check my volume pool utilization

```
  LV                                             VG             Attr       LSize   Pool                Origin                                      Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
   cinder-volumes-pool                            cinder-volumes twi-aotz--   1.49t                                                                 26.35  22.20
```

I can see that there is ~26% utiliation of that volume pool. Is there any way to monitor it. I currently use Zabbix for overall monitoring of servers and other services. But Zabbix supports monitoring of filesystem, not disks and LVM pools.

Do you know any solution which I can use to monitor it? Anything like some bash or python script which send mail over smtp when the data % is more than 80% or so?? Or some zabbix template??

Edit1:
I guess I can use this approach.

```
disk_usage=$(sudo lvs -a | grep -w cinder-volumes-pool | awk '$1 ~ /cinder-volumes-pool/ { POOL = $1 } { DISK += $5 } END { print DISK }')
```

I'll compare this var value with my threshold (50% or 80%). When it will match, I'll configure SMTP to send mail. It should be a decent solution. If you guys have something better, feel free to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this issue, and thus posting a solution in case anyone want help.
First of all, we will get the disk usage with `lvs -a` command. The following customization will get the exact value. Make sure you replace your LVM thin pool name in grep and awk regex.

```
sudo lvs -a | grep -w cinder-volumes-pool | awk '$1 ~ /cinder-volumes-pool/ { DISK += $5 } END { print DISK }'
```

Compare the value with the one you are getting for your volume pool in lvs -a command, if it is same, we can proceed. Otherwise, count its position and modify it in awk (from $5 to your Data% position).

In my case, I was already using Zabbix. So, I edited my zabbix agent file (/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf) and added the following line.

```
UserParameter=cinder-volumes.disk_usage,sudo lvs -a | grep -w cinder-volumes-pool | awk '$1 ~ /cinder-volumes-pool/ { DISK += $5 } END { print DISK }' | bc -l
```

UserParameter is used in Zabbix to send user defined keys from agent to Zabbix server. Here, cinder-volumes.disk_usage is my key name, and the command is value for that key.

Since my command needs root privilege, I modified zabbix-agent systemd unit to run as root (I know this is not the best approach, a better solution is always welcome). Restart your Zabbix Agent.

Confirm whether your custom key is working:

```
sudo zabbix_agent2 -t cinder-volumes.disk_usage
```

If you get the output value, go to Zabbix Dashboard. For your Host, create a new item with your key that you created in the previous step. Select Numeric (float) for type of information and Update Interval 1h and you are good to go.

After creating item, create triggers based on that item with expression

```
last(/Openstack control01 Linux Server/cinder-volumes.disk_usage,#1)>=80
```

For testing, create a trigger with lower value (under your current disk usage). If trigger is created, everything is fine. You can now create media alert (email, pagerduty, slack or anything) to receive alert for your trigger.